# waypoint plugin not initialising as expected

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use way point. I am unable to initialise the plugin. I want to use the sticky function to keep my header sticky. Since I have problem in IE11 if I use 'positon: sticky', I am trying to use this plugin. 
 Link to plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/mRhgVuXZSSX8QpPeeBbK?p=preview

index.html

```
 <body>
    <div id="section" class="section">
      <div class="heading">
        Header
          </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="heading">
              Sub-heading1
                </div>
              <ul>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>

                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>

                <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
              </ul></li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>

          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>

          <li>Sub-heading1 </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="sticky.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

  </body>
```

css code :

```
 <style media="screen">
  .sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
  }
  .sticky:before,
  .sticky:after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
  }
  .section {
    background: yellow;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    left: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  </style>
```

Here is the script initialisation and when i scroll nothing happens.

```
$(function() {
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
element: document.getElementById('section'),
handler: function(direction) {
  console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
}
```

})
    });

I My expectaion is that when I scroll the section container, waypoint initialises and renders the function nut nothing happens as of now.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or codePen where the same problem occurs?

Comment: Did you link jquery? is this jquery.js?

Comment: yes. It is jquery. I will link the fiddle

Comment: I have added plunkr link to the code

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, add the following to your css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

and you're missing the link to the script.js which initializes waypoint

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: the script i would have missed in hurry while adding the plunkr. But even if i add the changes u have mentioned to my css it is still not wokring

Comment: it's missing in your question as well

Comment: It works: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/yoEgZX try removing the part I asked you to add and it won't work anymore

Comment: make sure that you really aren't missing anything. And in Chrome pressing Ctrl + Shift + i you can open the developers tab. Maybe there is an error code that you could post if it still doesn't work...

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your help. I am just trying to get clarified here. I have the overflow set to scroll on element with id 'section'. So i am expecing when i scroll the 'section container' I get waypoint working. Now it seems like working on the page scroll. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: even if you comment the overflow it still works. Sadly I can't find a good explanation on why you have to use the height: 100% on body and html... I'll keep looking though and comment if I can find it.

Comment: If we comment the overflow, the scroll gets applied to the body element. In my code it applieS to section container(I think so, I am not sure if I have understood correct). I am not sure what is the purpose of  the element which we use in our script to initialize waypoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152647/discussion-between-kathara-and-jenny).